# IntelliJ Scala Plugin Scala Console CTRL+C exit infinite while(true) loop

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, while-loop, console

I am programming in Scala using IntelliJ with the default Scala plugin.

I am doing some threading exercises using the Scala Console, and I noticed that it was not possible to stop an infinite running process without stopping the Scala Console (then I have to reload everything in order to try again which is cumbersome).

Is there a way to stop a while(true){} loop process in the Scala Console without stopping the Scala Console.

I've tried with "CTRL+C" but it did not work, and I've been all over the internet trying to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: There is `cancelable in Global := true` see [sbt tricks](http://underscore.io/blog/posts/2015/11/09/sbt-commands.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sascha
Can you also tell me where I access these settings or where I can change this setting when running IntelliJ on Windows? :-)